# Why is writeToScript reporting that my script costs 0 resources?

Tags: plutus, minting, emulator, cost

I have the following minting script:

```
{-# INLINABLE verify_mint #-}
script :: () -> V2.ScriptContext  -> Bool
script () _ = (3::Integer) == 2+1
```

and the following off-chain code to mint a token:

```
trace :: Trace.EmulatorTrace ()
        trace = do 
            Extras.logInfo @Haskell.String "Starting..."
            handle <- Trace.activateContractWallet Test.w1 contract

            Trace.callEndpoint @"mint" handle ()
            Functor.void $ Trace.waitNSlots 5

        contract :: Contract () Schema Text ()
        contract = do
            Contract.logInfo @Haskell.String "Waiting..."
            Contract.selectList [ mint ] >> contract

        mint :: Promise () Schema Text ()
        mint  = Contract.endpoint @"mint" $ \() -> do
            let constraint = Constraints.mustMintCurrency (Scripts.mintingPolicyHash policy) "ABC" 1
            tx <- Contract.submitTxConstraintsWith @TScripts.Any (Constraints.plutusV2MintingPolicy policy) constraint
            Functor.void $ Contract.awaitTxConfirmed (Ledger.getCardanoTxId tx)
            Contract.logInfo @Haskell.String "Minted!"
```

However when I run `writeToScript` as follows:

```
let cmd = Scripts UnappliedValidators
    let config = ScriptsConfig "keystore-stats" cmd
    Haskell.print =<< writeScriptsTo config "x" trace Default.def
```

I get the following result:

```
(Sum {getSum = 0},ExBudget {exBudgetCPU = ExCPU 0, exBudgetMemory = ExMemory 0})
```

How can this be? Shouldn't minting require some resources?

Answer (score 0):

It should. `writeScriptsTo` is [buggy at the moment](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/main/plutus-contract/src/Plutus/Trace/Emulator/Extract.hs#L89) (not sure why, probably a placeholder has been set while we were working on it and we forgot to change it afterwards).

I'm creating a ticket to fix it.

Comment: Is there any other way to find out how much resources my script is taking in the meantime?

Comment: I didn't try it but you can use [plutus profiling](https://plutus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howtos/profiling-scripts.html) directly.

Comment: But how do I obtain the uplc executable? Running "cabal build" in the plutus-apps directory results in an error.